# Voltage regulator's input capacitor "Required if regulator is locate an appreciable distance from power supply filter."

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator

[The datasheet of a 78XX voltage regulator](https://cdn-reichelt.de/documents/datenblatt/A200/TEL78XX-L78XXC_E.pdf) states that the input capacitor is "Required if regulator is locate [sic!] an appreciable distance from power supply filter". What constitutes an "appreciable distance"? I'm adding a heat sink, which forces me to place the filter (or input) cap a bit off of the regulator. Maybe 10 mm or even further, depending on how I lay it out. Do I need to worry about that?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what the 78xx is powering. If you have a noisy load then the input cap obviously matters much more and I would provide one if the distance is more than an inch or two. Maybe provide a footprint and populate a cap if EMI testing shows that you need to (to constrain the loop area of high frequency currents). Use fat power traces to keep impedance low.

I wouldn't worry about 10mm from cap to 78xx at all.

Answer (score 1):

My general advice would be to add capacitors to the input of every regulator. They don't hurt (except your bill of materials), and usually help. And, for electrolytic capacitors it would be fine to place them 10mm away. If you also use ceramic capacitors for higher frequency filtering and loop stability, then these should be closer (but they're smaller, so you should be able to fit them closer). You should also in most circumstances add capacitors to the *output* of the regulator, as the regulator is usually powering components which produce large changes in current draw, and the regulator feedback loop must be made stable, for which capacitors help.

The reason for capacitors on the end of long tracks is to suppress noise picked up on those tracks. A strong enough noise source can affect even a short track, so there's no rule on the use of capacitors that's applicable for all circumstances. If you have noisy components such as switch-mode power supplies near to your track, or external connections (e.g. to a lab power supply), then definitely add capacitors. For shorter, internal tracks, you may get away without one, but as I said above unless it's critical to your layout or budget then just add some: 10uF or 22uF are fine for most op-amp based applications. If you have higher load, then add higher capacitance.